# Strange User-Agent discovered

Tags: javascript, windows, user-agent, meizu

I found strange user-agent while searching through my apache access.log. 
Are there anyone who had seen this user-agent before:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.108 Safari/537.36 MZBrowser/7.7.110-2019010410
```

I'm wondering how is it possible, because MZBrowser looks like a valid Meizu Browser identifier, but Windows NT 5.2 doesn't make sense in it at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: so someone can not be using windows server 2003 (I think that is it without looking it up)

Comment: Slightly off-topic: Why is this tagged with `javascript`? If you're trying to use the user-agent to customize the javascript for individual users, you should probably use [feature detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection) instead.

Comment: You can set a custom user-agent for embedded browsers and direct connections from applications.   Firefox also has/had a plugin for doing this.  Don't assume user-agents will always be valid.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely the **Desktop mode**'s user agent string.

You can switch browser to it following the [official user manual](http://meizu.tccm.com/files/MX3_M353_UM_EN.pdf) (p. 30, *Request desktop site*).